# the meaning of for

Tags: meaning

I wonder what is the meaning of for in this sentence. "Elizabeth suddenly sees Darcy for who he is" 
please explain the meaning with some examples. how can I say that sentence in another way?
 Bahman

Comment: 'See someone/something for who he is/what it is' is an idiom for 'see someone as they really are' / 'see something as it really is', not as he/it may appear at first glance. There are related expressions, I'd say less appropriate: 'love someone as he really is' has been used for 'love someone just as he is'. An attempt to pin a meaning on 'for' here would be, in my view, unprofitable.

Comment: I love the fact that with just one sentence, we all know what book you are reading.  :D

Comment: @MBurke One of Mark Hebden's Inspector Pel novels?

Comment: Yes, @MBurke , no doubt about it. Except that line ain't Jane Austen.

Comment: 'Elizabeth suddenly sees the true Darcy' is another way to put it.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a strange idiom, for it appears extremely redundant (if you can see someone, how can you not see them for who they are?). I expect this is particularly vexing to those not used to English as their first language.

The meaning of this phrase is to understand a person's true nature, or at least certain important attributes of their personality. It is usually employed when a person's actions suddenly reveal something about them which a another person might not have assumed based on their previous knowledge and/or assumptions. Usually, it refers to a negative quality which a person might want to keep hidden, or which might be surprising because it is not how a presumably good person would act. Frequently, it implies a drastic change in how a person feels about another, and whether their relationship can continue as it was.

Other ways to phrase this might be "Elizabeth suddenly understood Darcy's true nature." A more specific "and arbitrary" example might be "Darcy's treatment of the child made Elizabeth see him in a different light," or "Elizabeth felt that Darcy's behavior this evening had revealed his true colors."

Answer (score 1):

It's the same ***for = as = like = in the manner of*** usage as...

> *I want you **as/for** a friend, not [as/for] a lover*

OP's example could be replaced (somewhat less idiomatically) by...

> *She sees him **as** [who] he is*

...but note that syntactically we *can't* discard ***who*** (or ***what***, particularly with an inanimate referent) in the ***for*** version.